# Speeding up `badblocks` by tweaking its `-c` switch

Tags: debian, memory, performance, disk, badblocks

I have just tried upon tweaking the `badblocks` utility to use more RAM and **possibly** achieve a bit higher performance.

The exact command I am running is (without HDD's S/N):

```sh
badblocks -v -b 4096 -c 98304 -w -s /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD5000LPCX-24C6HT0_SN >> /root/spare-hdd-badblocks.log 2>&1 &
```

I do not use the `badblocks` tool very often, however, so if I may ask... What does the `-c` switch do exactly and why is it suggested to achieve higher speeds? Does it really eat more memory and if so, as I have plenty, could it possibly be wise to further increase it?

From its [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/badblocks):

> `-c`: Number of blocks is the number of blocks which are tested at a time. The default is 64.

I do not understand it, I just hope someone does.

---

Credit, math, and source of further valuable info:

http://www.pantz.org/software/badblocks/badblocksusage.html

---

My system: Debian 11 on a headless Xeon server with 32GB ECC RAM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `-c` flag controls the number of blocks tested in one go. By increasing this number you're reducing overhead (system calls), marginally improving performance. (Consider `dd` vs `dd bs=64M` as another example of this optimisation process.)

However, I'm less convinced that `badblocks` is even relevant these days. Disk firmware has got much more sophisticated and the OS no longer needs to omit faulty sectors as the disk does that for you itself. What's more, with SMART you can even get the disk to self-test regularly, and with SMART monitoring you'll be notified when (if) there's a problem - probably in enough time to replace the disk before you lose the data

Comment: Yep, and it's even worse on SSDs: The firmware will transparently compress badblocks writes which defeats the purpose. The same might happen on newer HDDs and I believe it even happens with -t random since badblocks has a bizarre definition of what's "random".

Comment: `dd bs=64M` is a strange example because it's not optimal unless you're copying between files / partitions on the same rotational disk, in which case a very large buffer decreases seeks.  Normally something like `bs=64k` or `128k` is good, half the size of L2 cache or less, so data is still hot in cache from the kernel's `copy_to_user` when the write system call's `copy_from_user` copies it back into kernel pagecache / write buffers.  But yes, `dd`'s default is way too small, costing lots of syscall overhead.

Comment: @Navin: Interesting; I thought SSD compression was a thing of the past ([Sandforce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SandForce) controllers, especially in OCZ SSDs), but this article from 2019 (https://blocksandfiles.com/2019/09/03/compression-inside-qlc-ssd-endurance/) suggests that at least some modern enterprise SSDs do it, e.g. from Seagate.  (Perhaps not a coincidence that Seagate acquired Sandforce, indirectly via LSI).  https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/l8hrh7/what_happened_to_dramless_ssd_with_hardware/ supports my impression that it's not widespread, seems just Seagate Nytro.